# highcharts - pulling data from HTML but converting the strings to number

Tags: highcharts

I have a HTML table whose `tbody` `td`s contains strings, specifically dollar amounts like $1,500, can I `parseInt()` those before they are read into HC?

The API has some methods under the `data` attribute like `beforeParse` but the documentation implies that it only works for CSVs.  Are there any methods I could use for this?

Answer (score 0):

You are right, `beforeParse` works only for data from CSV, but you can also modify your data in `complete` or `parsed` callback function.

```
complete: function(options) {
  options.series.forEach(s => {
    s.data.forEach(point => {
      point[1] = Number(point[1].slice(1));
    });
  });
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/98mayuts/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data.complete

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data.parsed